# Find $\int_{-1}^{2}(5x^3+7x^2-9x+4)dx$ by Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I want to determine this integral $\int_{-1}^{2}(5x^3+7x^2-9x+4)dx$ by Riemann sums. Clearly we can take

$$\Delta x=\frac{2-(-1)}{n}$$ And $$x_i=-1+\frac{i3}{n}$$

Then

$$\int_{-1}^{2}(5x^3+7x^2- 9x+4)dx\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\left(5(-1+\frac{i3}{n})^3+7(-1+\frac{i3}{n})^2-9(-1+\frac{i3}{n})+4\right)\frac{3}{n}$$

Clearly the expression can be simplified a bit more, however after that I don't know what else I can do to get to the value of the integral.

Comment: Don't forget the $dx$'s.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the formulas
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n 1 &= n \\
\sum_{i=1}^n i &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 &= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \\
\end{align}

Comment: I think I'm making a mistake in the calculations, can you give me a hint of what the expression looks like before using the series?

Comment: $405 i^3/n^4 - 216 i^2/n^3 - 72 i/n^2 + 45/n$

Comment: Thank you for this